# Ember: handling JSON response from ember-network promise in component

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement a simple autosuggest in a component.  I'm testing fastboot and therefore am using ember-network to communicate with my API.  I'm not using ember-data right now.  Whether or not this is the "ember" way to do it is a different question...I'm just trying to get this to work.

My component JS:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import fetch from 'ember-network/fetch';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    searchText: null,

    loadAutoComplete(query) {
        let suggestCall = 'http://my.api.com/suggest?s=' + query;
        return fetch(suggestCall).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        });     
    },

    searchResults: Ember.computed('searchText', function() {
        let searchText = this.get('searchText');
        if (!searchText) { return; }
        let searchRes = this.loadAutoComplete(searchText);
        return searchRes;
    })
});
```

And in the template:

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}

{{ log "TEMPALTE RESULTS" searchResults }}
{{#each-in searchResults as |result value|}}
<li>{{result}} {{value}}</li>
{{/each-in}}
```

The template log directive is outputting this in my console:

[image: console]

The data is in "suggestions", so I know the fetch is working.  I just can't figure out how to get at it.  I can't loop over '_result'.  What do I need to do to parse this and use it in a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning promise from computed property is not just straight forward, it's little tricky.

Option1. You can use [ember-concurrency](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency) addon for this use case. You can look at [auto complete feature explanation doc](http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/examples/autocomplete)

Your component code,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { task, timeout } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    searchText: null,

    searchResults: task(function*(str) {
        this.set('searchText', str);
        let url = `http://my.api.com/suggest?s=${str}`;
        let responseData = yield this.get('searchRequest').perform(url);
        return responseData;
    }).restartable(),
    searchRequest: task(function*(url) {
        let requestData;
        try {
            requestData = Ember.$.getJSON(url);
            let result = yield requestData.promise();
            return result;
        } finally {
            requestData.abort();
        }
    }).restartable(),
});
```

and your component hbs code,

```
<input type="text" value={{searchText}} onkeyup={{perform searchResults value="target.value"  }}>
<div> 
     {{#if searchResults.isIdle}}
        <ul>
            {{#each searchResults.lastSuccessful.value as |data| }}
            <li> {{data}} </li>
            {{else}}
             No result 
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{else}}
        Loading...
    {{/if}} 
</div>
```

Option2. You can return DS.PromiseObject or DS.PromiseArray

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import fetch from 'ember-network/fetch';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    searchText: null,

    loadAutoComplete(query) {
        let suggestCall = 'http://my.api.com/suggest?s=' + query;
        return fetch(suggestCall).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        });
    },

    searchResults: Ember.computed('searchText', function() {
        let searchText = this.get('searchText');
        if (!searchText) { return; }
        //if  response.json returns object then you can use DS.PromiseObject, if its an array then you can use DS.PromiseArray        
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
            promise: this.loadAutoComplete(searchText)
        });
    })
});
```

Reference ember igniter article- [The Guide to Promises in Computed Properties](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/)

Comment: the concurrency thing is really interesting.  I looked at it and immediately thought it wouldn't work with fastboot, but it does!  I think this will be super handy going forward.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IMO, it is not a good practice to call a remote call from a computed property. You should trigger it from input component/helper.

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..." key-up=(action loadAutoComplete)}}
```

And the new `loadAutoComplete` would be like:

```
loadAutoComplete(query) {
    //check query is null or empty...
    let suggestCall = 'http://my.api.com/suggest?s=' + query;
    return fetch(suggestCall).then((response) => {
        this.set('searchResults', response.json());
    });     
},
```

Your `searchResults` will no longer need to be a computed property. Just a property.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I think 'searchResults' is still ultimately a non-iterable promise though, correct?  I think kumkanillam's PromiseObject suggestion would need to be worked in, correct?

Comment: No, `searchResults` will be the result array (iterable).