# Ember helper that returns the resolved value of a promise

Tags: ember.js

How can I get [this helper](https://github.com/chroaster/super-rentals/blob/master/app/helpers/city-temperature.js) to return the result of a promise?

```
// helpers/city-temperature.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  weather: Ember.inject.service(),
  compute(params) {
    let location = params[0];
    let temperaturePromise = this.get('weather').getTemperaturePromise(location);
    return temperaturePromise.then((value)=>{
      return value;
    });
  }
});
```

I modeled it after code from [this discussion](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/helper-and-returning-the-resolved-value-of-a-promise/10975/3). It's retrieving the value from the remote API but I'm not able to get it to display in the component. And I want to do it without passing a DOM element around.

The complete app code is [here](https://github.com/chroaster/super-rentals).

Comment: Hmm, the fact that [ember-promise-helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers/) exists suggests that what I'm trying to do is not that straightforward. The readme there says, "When Ember's templates encounter a promise, it won't re-render it when the promise is resolved or rejected."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to experts from the embercommunity, the answer is `helpers` are not promise aware and we shouldn't use them for returning the resolved value of a promise.

I got the desired result using a component, so that is something to consider if you find yourself in this situation.

Comment: I don't think this answer is valid for recent versions of Ember from Octane.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, returning Promise instead of helper you can try computed property. You can create computed property which depends on `location`. Refer this [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c6131fc158aea5b5a796c119453e9812?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',  
  result:Ember.computed(function(){
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
        promise: Ember.RSVP.resolve({name:'Kumkanillam'}).then((result) => { return result;})
         });
  })
});
```

inside hbs,

```
{{#if result.isPending}}
  Loading...
{{else}}
  value: {{result.name}}
{{/if}}
```

For another approach, you can [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337326/5771666)

- Usual best practice is avoiding the computed property which returns Promise.